# Laravel 5 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67. Como resolver isso sem usar a classe FORM?

Tags: laravel-5, token

Tenho um projeto em php/Html e estou passando ele para laravel. O que quer dizer que muita coisa eu não vou criar do zero e quero aproveitar ao máximo o que já está escrito.

No momento estou trabalhando com um formulário. No código original ele está escrido usando action="#" assim:

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sky-form1" class="sky-form">

....

<button id="btn_login" type="submit" class="btn-u btn-block">Go Hme</button>
</form>
```

Então no JavaScript eu respondo ao evento click e direciono para página desejada:

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on("click", "#btn_login", function(){
           //alert("ok");
           //return false;          
           $('form').attr('action','home.php');    

      }); //End of $(document).on("change", ...    
});//End of $(function(){
```

Ao click do btn_login o usuário é direcionado para a página home.

Nota: o código não está completo, apenas as partes mais importantes. Não tem teste de login ou teste de usuário e etc. É apenas um botão dentro de um formulário na página index que deveria direcionar para a página home.

Agora passando para Laravel:

Tenho esse código das rotas que funciona. Ele me direciona para a página home **se eu escrever na URL** `myApp.com/home`

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home',['usertype'=>"2"]);
});
```

E a página home é acessada, como o esperado.

Para o cenário de apertar o botão do form para ser direcionado para home eu fiz o seguinte código de rota:

```
Route::post('/home', function () {
        return view('home',['usertype'=>"2"]);
    });
```

Usei **post** e essa foi a única mudança.

No javascript fiz uma pequena alteração tbm:

```
$(function(){
          $(document).on("click", "#btn_login", function(){
               //alert("ok");
               //return false;          
               $('form').attr('action','home');    

          }); //End of $(document).on("change", ...    
 });//End of $(function(){
```

Mudei o **home.php** para **home** (que é o esperado pela rota).

Então essa é a lógica:

O Usuário aperta o botão login, o javascript passar o `action` do formulário de `action="#"` para `action="home"` e a rota de laravel captura a requisição e retorna a pagina desejada. Está funcionando.

O único problema é que quando a página home tentar ser acessada após o click, recebo o erro: `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67`

Imagino que seja a vericação do **_token** para evitar ataques **CSRF**.

Como eu não estou usando a classe **FORM** do laravel o token não é gerado dentro do meu form.

Então a minha pergunta é como resolver esse problema sem usar a classe FORM?
Tem como eu criar o input hidden e colocar o valor do token manualmente? Onde acho esse valor? E por último, existe um token para cada formulário?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode colocar isto dentro do form (caso esteja a usar [blade templating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('ROUTA DO POST')}}">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
   ...
</form>
```

`{!! csrf_field() !!}` produz qualquer coisa como: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="8VI98KkDdCdHd0Wn62ha8OONrTAvViDFOW383ux2">`, assim vai mandar o token via `post` para o servidor juntamente com os outros dados.

Pode também incluir o input do [token csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection) 'manualmente', assim:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
...
```

Para responder à sua outra questão. Pode desativar a verificação deste token para as rotas que quiser (mas acho que não é [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729415/disable-csrf-in-laravel-for-specific-route) que quer). Então, sim, precisa de enviar um token sempre que fizer um request tipo post

Comment: Perfeito... funcinou. Agora a última pergunta. Existe um token para cada formulario? Ou existe um token standard para cada projeto?

Comment: O token é gerado do lado servidor (built-in em php no framework Laravel) quando chama a função `csrf_token();`. Pode verificar isto fazendo `dd(csrf_token());`. Isto vai gerar uma string pseudo-random que fica guardada no servidor, para depois ser validada (verificação entre a que foi mandada no formulário e a que o servidor tem guardada)

Comment: Ok então deve ser um múmero pseudo aleatório o que quer dizer, um para cada requisição. Correto?

Comment: Sim, para cada requisição que vá fazer tipo post precisa 'prepara-la' para enviar também o token, inclusive para chamadas de ajax. A não ser que não queira, inclui um link na resposta para essa eventualidade. Mas escusa de se preocupar com isso, é tudo feito automáticamente quando chama `csrf_token();` e envia o token via post

Comment: Para responder à sua questão mais linearmente: sim, para cada formulário que vá enviar a requisição como sendo post (`method="POST"`) precisa... Desculpe só agora que li melhor a sua duvida no comentário, escusava de ter explicado tanto :P